# Compiler Error:falied to determine size of array size identifier

Tags: c++, arrays, compiler-errors

below code for merging two arrays,on line 5-6 why one is compiling fine while other shows error "Intializer failed to determine size of result"

```
 void Merge(int first[],int second[],int f_length,int s_length){
     int total_length=f_length+s_length;
     int f_count=0;
     int s_count=0;
     **int result[total_length]**;//this is working fine
     *int result[]=new int[total_length]*;//Generating compiler error
     for(int i=0;i<total_length;i++){
            if(first[f_count]<second[s_count] && f_count<f_length)
                result[i]=first[f_count++];
            else
                 result[i]=second[s_count++];
             }
     for(int i=0;i<total_length;i++)
             cout<<result[i]<<endl;
     }
```

Comment: Added clarification :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C++ defining an array requires that its size would be a constant expression at compile time. So this definition

```
 int result[total_length];
```

is invalid because total_length is not a constant expression.

If you mean the following line

```
int result[]=new int[total_length];
```

then the correct syntax is

```
int *result = new int[total_length];
```

The compiler reports the error bacause it can not determine the size of the array from expression

```
new int[total_length]
```

due to using invalid syntax construction.

Apart from this your function is invalid. You do not check whether s_count exceeds s_length. Even this invalid condition

```
if(first[f_count]<second[s_count] && f_count<f_length)
```

should be written at least as

```
if ( f_count<f_length && first[f_count]<second[s_count] )
```

because you may not dereference pointer that points beyond the last element of an array. That is at first you dereference the pointer `first[f_count]<second[s_count]` and only after you check whether it is an element after the last element in the array `f_count<f_length`

Comment: Better but you can see in the deleted answer that VLA clearly works for the OP so it might be useful to indicate that some compilers allow it as an extension in C++.

Comment: @Shafik Yaghmour There is no variable length array. There is an incorrect syntax.

Comment: great Thanks, I realized the mistake now. I think my compiler is allowing the syntax for int result[total_length],although it might not work for other compilers.

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour: Using VLA in C++ is still a violation of the standard which might cause problems in the future. OP should stick with `std::vector`. Take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17899274/g-variable-size-array-no-warning

Comment: Clearly works in both [clang and gcc](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5225040330e78ad8) in C++ with a warning but it works and is legitimate in both.

Comment: @baerenfaenger compilers are explicitly allowed to implement extensions as long as they don't break standard code. I am not advocating for it but it is reality there are significant extensions used in the real world.